# Entering special characters in database

Tags: python, sqlite, special-characters

I am scanning my system and entering file names into a sqlite3 database using python.

One of the files happens to have a special character in its name and it produces an error while inserting the record. This is the file name.

```
 a¿.mp3
```

this is the query

```
self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO TRACKS VALUES (?)", i)
```

Also due to the special character, I am unable to encode it in utf-8.

Is there some other encoding which I can use to add this data into the database?

Answer (score 0):

You can try utf-16 encoding, or adding '' around the special character.

Comment: would utf 16 successfully encode other data? or would I have to keep checking for the kind of data and encode accordingly?

Comment: I have not tested, but would assume that it would work, as long as you open it as utf-16 later on aswell.

Comment: This is my source dbInput = [(unicode(i,'utf-16'), ) for i in matches]

while some are regular input and some are special characters, i receive the error as 
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf16' codec can't decode byte 0x33 in position 82: truncated data for regular input.

Comment: Maybe you need to filter them then

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `os.walk` for this? If you do, pass the directory name not as a bare string but as a unicode object, such as `os.walk(u'/some/path')` to get all the files in unicode. Then you can encode them in utf-8 (or utf-16 if utf-8 is not enough) with `filename.encode('utf-8')`